# Standard URL format for CMIS? base URL + repository + local path

Tags: url, cmis

By an URL, is there a standard way to express the way to a subfolder of a given repository of a particular [CMIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html) server?

For instance:

- CMIS server: `http://server/alfresco/service/cmis`
- repository within this server: `myrepo7`
- subfolder within this repository: `proposals/eurostar/`

Is there a standard way to express the whole thing as a URL?

If I join the whole thing with slashes, I will not be able to tell which part is the repo:

```
http://server/alfresco/service/cmis/myrepo7/proposals/eurostar/
```

Maybe there is a syntax with dashes or something?

```
http://server/alfresco/service/cmis#myrepo7#proposals/eurostar/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CMIS URLs of the AtomPub binding are repository specific. You shouldn't rely on any observations.

The CMIS 1.1 browser binding defines what you want to achieve here, interoperable across all CMIS repositories. But there are not many repositories that support this binding, yet.

Comment: OK, so I will just store the 3 parts of information separately. Looking forward to the browser binding :-) https://wiki.oasis-open.org/cmis/Browser%20Binding